# ActiveRecord::Reflections methods - modelname_ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I would like to know how to get the the plural ids method from reflections
I have following class

```
class Tale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :x
  has_many :y
```

I use

```
Tale.reflect_on_associations
```

to access association x and y

I can use

```
x.klass #=> x
x.class_name #=> "x"
x.plural_name #=> "xs"
```

what i need is a way to get the methods association_name_ids from reflections

example

```
:x_ids
```

So i can use it as follows

```
tale_instance_object.send(:x_ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String#singularize`:

```
tale_instance_object.send(x.name.to_s.singularize + "_ids") # => [1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Also, you can use built-in `#ids_reader` method:

```
my_model_instance.association(:x).ids_reader # => [1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Comment: I want to use built in methods that are part of the ActiveRecord::Reflections module ... like .plural_name on a reflection gives me its pluralized name to be used to fetch all association objects through send .. model.send(reflection.plural_name)

Comment: is ids_reader the exact method name. It is not working on any model or reflection. I .ids as the method, but i want something like     tale_instance_object.send(:x_ids) # => [1,2,3]

Comment: You should call in on association. Not on instance object itself. It works: `table_instance_object.association(:x).ids_reader`. What's your Rails version?

Comment: Rails - 4.2.0 ruby 2.1.5p273 on windows

Comment: Did you understand that you should call that method on association object, not ActiveRecord instance? If you didn't please read my answer again, I added more clear example of calling that method.

Comment: Yes. Also found method table_instance_object.association(:x).ids_writer(array)

Comment: Well, if using `ids_writer` is what you need you should accept my answer :)